# ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance (0)'}

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I am going through the freecodecamp course on Youtube and have caught an error regarding when I run. I have connected it to local blockchain ganache and using local address and private key. I have also set the gas price using "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price but still it's showing me error and i dont know why.

This is the error:

```
PS C:\Users\harsh\demos\web3_py_simple_storage> python deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\harsh\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 52, in <module>
    transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\web3\contract.py", line 684, in buildTransaction
    return fill_transaction_defaults(self.web3, built_transaction)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\web3\_utils\transactions.py", line 114, in fill_transaction_defaults
    default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\web3\_utils\transactions.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    'gas': lambda web3, tx: web3.eth.estimate_gas(tx),
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", 
line 855, in estimate_gas
    return self._estimate_gas(transaction, block_identifier)
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\web3\manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking  
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "C:\Users\harsh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\web3\manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'gas required exceeds allowance (0)'}
```

This here is my entire code that i have used:

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json
from web3 import Web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

load_dotenv()

install_solc("0.6.0")

with open("SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
            }
        },
    },
)
with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

## Get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

## Get ABI
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

## For connecting to rinkeby
w3 = Web3(
    Web3.HTTPProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/56b484f4e0f441fc97afe52fa27701d8")
)
chain_id = 4
my_address = "0x11F0BB2699A0F11CbC2Cb18a0a543a57ba1e17DA"
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")

## Create the contrat in python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
## Get latest transactions
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
## 1. Build a transation
## 2. Sign a transation
## 3. send a transation
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
## send this transaction
print("Deploying contract...")
tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
print("Deployed!")
## contract ABI
## contract address
simple_storage = w3.eth.contract(address=tx_receipt.contractAddress, abi=abi)
## call
## transact

## Initail value of favorite number
print(simple_storage.functions.retrieve().call())
print("Updating contract...")
store_transaction = simple_storage.functions.store(15).buildTransaction(
    {
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce + 1,
    }
)
signed_store_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
    store_transaction, private_key=private_key
)
send_store_tx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_store_txn.rawTransaction)
tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_store_tx)
print("Updated!")
print(simple_storage.functions.retrieve().call())
```

Any ideas to solve this error?

Comment: that error type means something is worng with your contract code. you should paste your contract code as well

Comment: @yilmaz
i don't think my contract code is wrong.

Comment: @yilmaz
i don't see any issue in code.  
'pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract SimpleStorage{
uint256 favoriteNumber;
struct People{uint256 favoriteNumber;string name;}
People[] public people;
mapping(string => uint256)public nameToFavoriteNumber;
function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber)public{favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;}
function retrieve() public view returns(uint256){return favoriteNumber;}
function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber)public{
    people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
    nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;}
}'

Comment: hi @block where you able to solve this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to switch to sepolia testnet with their chain id 11155111. The Goerli test net was giving my problems.